# Loading Heavy Graphics

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a game but before that i am creating **all the graphics that will be used in it** but here is the problem.

### Problem

The current games **graphics size is 50MB** and might increase as all the graphic work is not done yet and it is not possible to load 50 MB every time when the user runs the game. So, please tell me this if it is possible to **downloaded all the graphics on the first run and use it again when the user runs the game again**?

If yes then please help me by giving a piece of code snippet or any article related to it. Platform : ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of all the different caching mechanisms:

1. Http Caching. You may read more about it [here](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/). Especially the section "2. Expires"
2. HTML5 has the concept of local storage and you can possibly take advantage of that as well. You can read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage).
3. Try and compressing the graphics. You can read more [here](http://webappsuccess.com/web-app-performance.html). Especially the section "Minimize payload size".

Good luck and hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can download all the graphics on the first run & **cache it**. This will improve the performance tremendously.

Best practice is to use a CDN/Cache Server.

Refer to the following article for catching: [Link](https://hollyit.net/blog/caching-heavy-queries-good-or-bad) & [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362893/caching-data-on-a-heavy-load-web-server)

Comment: but how will i be able to access it from cache?